# JavaFX function plots are different than in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: math, plot, javafx, wolframalpha

I have created a calculator application which is supposed to plot graphs.User gets a textbox where he can enter function formula, which is then validated and parsed to ChartXY and so on to draw it.Basicaly I am using for all my functions libraries from javafx.I have spotted that my results are quite different.Most of the functions run very well but some functions differ, it's like I have real part + imaginary part but wolfram has also it's mirror reflection added.Plese look at my screenshots.

This example is regarding log(x) domain (-6,6) codomain (-2,2)

Wolfram Alpha complex graph:
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2uij7l2.jpg

My calculator app screenshot:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2m7xoi9.jpg

Another example is for log(sin(x)) domain(-6.3,6.3) codomain (-7,2)

Wolfram real: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2a5hoif.jpg

Wolfram complex: http://oi59.tinypic.com/kesq49.jpg

My calculator screenshot:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2v13qpu.jpg

arctan(tan(x)) for domain(-6.3,6.3) codomain(-2,2)

Wolfram plot: http://oi58.tinypic.com/hupze0.jpg

My application plot: http://oi62.tinypic.com/8wktmr.jpg

My question is: Is it supposed to be like this, if not then why is it like this and can it be fixed ?

Here is part of my class which contains all the parsing

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
private TextField domainTextField;
@FXML
private TextField codomainTextField;
@FXML
private LineChart coordinateLineChart;
@FXML
private TextField functionTextField;
@FXML
private NumberAxis xNumberAxis;
@FXML
private NumberAxis yNumberAxis;
@FXML
private ComboBox lineStyleComboBox;
@FXML
private ComboBox lineThiknessComboBox;
@FXML
private ColorPicker colorPicker;
@FXML
private Pane numericPane;
@FXML
private TextField descriptionTextField;
@FXML
private Label descriptionLabel;
@FXML
private VBox legendVBox;
@FXML
private CheckBox modificationModeCheckBox;
@FXML
private AnchorPane toSnapshot;

Stage stage;
MessageBox msgBox;
Intervals intervals = new Intervals();
LinkedList<FunctionViewHelper> functions = new LinkedList<FunctionViewHelper>();
boolean axisXdescriptionFlag = true;
boolean editingMode = false;
int editingFunctionId = 0;
int fontFactor = 0;
ObservableList<XYChart.Series> seriesListChart = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ArrayList<XYChart.Series> lastSeries = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>();
ArrayList<CustomFunction> exp4jCustomFunction = new ArrayList<CustomFunction>();

// Draws a graph
private void drawFormula(Calculable expression, ArrayList<String> conditions, String cssStyle) throws ScriptException {
    ArrayList<XYChart.Series> seriesList = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>();
    seriesList.add(new XYChart.Series());
    double lastY = 0;
    for (double x = intervals.domainStart; x < intervals.domainEnd; x += 0.009) {
        if (Validator.ifAllConditionsTrue(conditions, x)) {
            if (x != intervals.domainStart) lastY = expression.calculate();
            expression.setVariable("x", x);
            if (Math.abs(lastY - expression.calculate()) > Const.brakeLineConst)
                seriesList.add(new XYChart.Series());
            seriesList.get(seriesList.size() - 1).getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x, expression.calculate()));
        }
    }

    seriesListChart.addAll(seriesList);
    lastSeries.addAll(seriesList);

    setSeriesStyle(seriesList, cssStyle);
}

// Parsing string to Calculable which we can draw.
    private Calculable buildExpression(String expression) throws UnparsableExpressionException, UnknownFunctionException {
        return new ExpressionBuilder(expression)
                .withVariableNames("x")
                .withCustomFunctions(exp4jCustomFunction)
                .build();
    }
 private void drawButtonHandler() {
        //TODO remove
        //domainTextFieldOnChange();
        Function function = null;
        if (!Validator.validateFofEmptyFields(domainTextField, functionTextField)) {
            msgBox.show("You have to specify domain and formula.");
            return;
        }
        if (!Validator.validateIntervals(intervals, codomainTextField)) {
            msgBox.show("Specify proper domain and codomain.");
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (!editingMode) {
                function = new Function(functionTextField.getText(), colorPicker.getValue(), (String) lineStyleComboBox.getValue(),
                        lineThiknessComboBox.getValue().toString());
                colorPicker.setValue(Const.getNextColor());
            } else {
                function = getByFunctionId(editingFunctionId).function;
                function.formula = functionTextField.getText();
                seriesListChart.removeAll(getByFunctionId(editingFunctionId).series);
            }
            ArrayList<String> conditions = new ArrayList<String>();
            drawFunctionReq(function.formula, conditions, function.getCss());
            if (!editingMode)
                functions.add(new FunctionViewHelper(function, addLegendFunctionView(function), new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>(lastSeries)));
            else {
                getByFunctionId(editingFunctionId).series = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>(lastSeries);
                ((Label) getByFunctionId(editingFunctionId).view.getChildren().get(1)).setText(function.formula);
            }
        } catch (UnknownFunctionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            msgBox.show("Unknown function.");
        } catch (UnparsableExpressionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            msgBox.show("Unparsable expression.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            msgBox.show("Unknown error.");
        } finally {
            lastSeries.clear();
        }
    }
 @FXML
    private void domainTextFieldOnChange() {
        domainTextField.setStyle("");
        try {
            intervals.setDomain(domainTextField.getText());
            xNumberAxis.lowerBoundProperty().set(intervals.domainStart);
            xNumberAxis.upperBoundProperty().set(intervals.domainEnd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            domainTextField.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: red;");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void codomainTextFieldOnChange() {
        codomainTextField.setStyle("");
        if (!codomainTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                intervals.setCodomain(codomainTextField.getText());

                yNumberAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
                yNumberAxis.setUpperBound(intervals.codomainEnd);
                yNumberAxis.setLowerBound(intervals.codomainStart);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                codomainTextField.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: red;");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else yNumberAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry it's late... It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WA is correct. In the imaginary component, which is arg(z), there should be a jump from pi to 0 at z=0. The real component is log(|z|).

Guess into the blue: Be sure to use arctan2 when computing angles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have added parsing code from my application.I don't really see how I could fix it, because it looks like the problem is in the library.Could You tell me if it is fixable after looking into code ?

Comment: Are you sure that your expression evaluator uses functions over the complex numbers? It seems that for negative x you get a "nothing" as result.

Comment: At first I was sure that I don't but now I am really confused especially since that rectangular shape function appears there ( which from what I know is not real part).

Comment: That could be due to the singularity of the logarithm. If the default value for "nothing" is very large and since log(0.009) is very large in the negative direction you get a vertical line at zero. Just print the values in the value list. Or use a larger range, -10..10 for instance.

Comment: What about log(sin(x)) case ?

Comment: This has the same problems. The real logarithm is not defined for negative arguments, the return value should be NaN, but I'm not sure if Java supports this double value.

Comment: I have checked Nan values and it occured to be the problem.Library was saving Nan values to the list and then trying to draw it. I have added  if(!Double.isNaN(expression.calculate()))before the drawing and now it is good, although it did not solve the problem in more complex functions.

Comment: If no complex arithmetic is available, the components of `log(x+i*y)` are computable as `0.5*log(x*x+y*y)` and `atan2(y,x)`, in your case both at `y=0`, for non-singular plots use `y=1e-6` or something similarly small.